# I couldn't exist row in database with where clause

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a row with field `CAPACITY_STRING="كاردان تكنسين تعميرات شبكه بالا سري"` but when I execute query it couldn't retrieve that.
My query is:

```
public Domain.ViewPost GetByCapacityString(string capacityString)
        {
            return this.Data().Where(p => p.CAPACITY_STRING == capacityString).SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

Above code return `null` while I have that row.

Comment: Could you possibly compare the strings in a diff program? Could you try and use String.Equals(..., StringComparison.InvariantCulture)?

Comment: Please show the `this.Data()` implementation. What collation is the column? Is there a charset in your connection string?

Comment: @CodeCaster other String search is ok. my problem just for ths